# PHP XML Special Characters. Words Support like "Göteborg"

Tags: php, xml

I used DOM to create XML using PHP.
My issue is that some European words are not supported while XML generates.
for example.

> **Göteborg** display as **GÃ¶teborg**
>   while 
>   **Västra Götaland** display as **Västra Götaland** (same)
>   Again **MARABOU MJÖLKCHOKLAD 200G** display as **MARABOU MJÃ–LKCHOKLAD 200G**
>   But **Östergötland** display as **Östergötland** (same)

Encoding is `UTF-8` and I use `html_entity_decode` to escape some characters.

if I use this code to test

```
$ship2city = utf8_encode('Götaland');
echo utf8_decode($ship2city).'<br>';
```

it prints "Götaland" but somehow its not working for XML

**Dynamic Code which generate XML**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
//$dom->xmlStandalone = true;
$document = $dom->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('DOCUMENT')
);
$order = $document->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('ORDER')
);
$oh = $order->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('OH')
);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml_oh_element_array); $i++) {
    $reportVariable = $oh->appendChild(
        $dom->createElement($xml_oh_element_array[$i])
    );
    if($i == 1){
        $reportVariable->appendChild(
            $dom->createCDATASection($xml_oh_element_data_array[$i])
        );
    }else{
        $reportVariable->appendChild(
            $dom->createTextNode($xml_oh_element_data_array[$i])
        );
    }

}

if(count($order_product_data_xml) > 0) {
    $j=0;
    foreach ($order_product_data_xml as $opd) {
        $price = number_format((float)$opd['price'], 2, '.', '');
        $price = str_replace(".","",$price);
        $or = $order->appendChild($dom->createElement('OR'));
            $order_product_data_xml = array($j,$opd['model'],$opd['name'],$opd['quantity'],$opd['unit'],$opd['weight'],'',$price,'','','','', $opd['model']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml_or_element_array); $i++) {
                if($i == 2){
                    $product_name = mb_convert_encoding($order_product_data_xml[$i], 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($order_product_data_xml[$i]));
                    $reportVariable = $or ->appendChild(
                    $dom->createElement($xml_or_element_array[$i], utf8_decode($product_name))
                );
                }else{
                    $reportVariable = $or ->appendChild(
                    $dom->createElement($xml_or_element_array[$i], $order_product_data_xml[$i])
                );
                }

            }
        $j++;
    }
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->save('Order'.$order_data_xml["order_id"].'.xml');
```

Comment: There simply is not enough information here to answer your question. Can you for starters supply the actual code that you use to generate the XML?

Comment: @apokryfos Edited

Comment: Where does the data come from? What encoding is it in? Is the origin data sane and all in a uniform encoding?

Comment: Make sure your PHP file is also UTF-8 encoded, there should be no need to call `utf8_encode()`.

Comment: There should also be absolutely no need for any `mb_convert_encoding` or `mb_detect_encoding`. You're willy-nilly converting encodings left and right here… no wonder something isn't lining up.

Comment: Perhaps start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: If you check the site at http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html it says "the problem is being caused by UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as Windows-1252 (or ISO 8859-1) bytes" so it may be a problem with your viewer.

Comment: Yes, PHP encodeing is UTF-8, @deceze data came from database and if I simply print it, its ok, but it is not ok while print in XML

Comment: @deceze Thanks for link

Comment: "Came from database" ***how*** exactly…?

Comment: @apokryfos its work fine on my system (local, Win7 WAMP, PHP 5.5), issue is from server (Cent OS, php 5.3).

Comment: @deceze I use opencart and fatch all data by order_id for perticular order --   $this->load->model('checkout/order');
                    $order_data_xml = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

Comment: If some special chars print correctly, while others get out wrong, you may want to check how this data get into your database in the first place. If some of them are scrambled in there, it will be a harsh job to have them all fixed by the time you read the data.

Comment: Maybe your problem is the charset of the database, set it before the first query/update in your PHP script (enter new data to test it). If you are working with MySql, have a look at the examples in the section [UTF-8 in MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).